# Multiple annotations found at this line:

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi guys I'm totally new to programming and need some help, and I hope one of you lovely people can help me:

When I run the AVD emulator I then click my button and I get an error saying "Unfortunately, Eventrecorder has stopped".

This is what my LogCat says:

```
04-11 22:08:10.415: D/dalvikvm(544): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-11 22:08:10.955: D/(544): Created
04-11 22:08:11.445: D/gralloc_goldfish(544): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-11 22:08:19.615: D/AndroidRuntime(544): Shutting down VM
04-11 22:08:19.615: W/dalvikvm(544): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3034)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  ... 11 more
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.eventrecorder/com.example.eventrecorder.NewEvent}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.example.eventrecorder.MainActivity.showAddForm(MainActivity.java:45)
04-11 22:08:19.655: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: This is a really confusing question since the problem you've stated in the title can only happen before you run your app (and your app cannot run until you fixed it).  The logcat is from a run time error and seems clear to me - `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.eventrecorder/com.example.eventrecorder.NewEvent}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file does not have an `<activity>` element with an `android:name` attribute of `com.example.eventrecorder.NewEvent`.

If `NewEvent` is supposed to be an activity, you need to add the associated `<activity>` element.

If `NewEvent` is not supposed to be an activity, go to line 45 of `MainActivity`, in your `showAddForm()` method, and fix the `Intent` that you are using with `startActivity()` to be one that points to an actual activity.